# Find percentage value of expression in graph

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, geometric-measure-theory

I've got measured values by bending 5 flex sensors from 0° to 180° (see graph), but when I want to backward calculate the bent angle from certain value I struggle with the non-linear behavior.

Lets say I want know angle from value 10000 of grey graph curve.

[image]

Comment: Are you supposed to know about smoothing splines ?

Comment: I don't know if smoothed spline would help. Problem is, that I have to take highest and lowest value from the graph, compare it with sensor data, which is float value and evaluate angle. When I only know that max angle is 180° and min 0° the only solution, as I see it now is via percentages.

Comment: Well, the data have so much noise that you probably need some preprocessing of them. This was just an idea.